# Замена цвета изображения используя css

Tags: css, png, цвета

Как изменить цвет кота?

https://codepen.io/Marticka/pen/MWegpjr

```css
.wrapper {
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
height:95vh;
}
/* cat body */
.cat {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  height: 100px;
/*   margin: 20px auto; */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.cat img {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  top: -46px;
}

/* cat's years styles */
.ears{
  position:absolute
}

.ear {
  width:0;
  border-left:10px solid transparent;
  border-right:10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:20px solid pink;
  position: relative;
}

.eLeft {
  left: -49px;
  top: -16px;
  transform: rotate(-48deg);
}
.eRight {
  left: 49px;
  top: -36px;
  transform: rotate(48deg);
}

/* cat's eyes */
.eye {
  position: absolute;
  width:28px;
  height:28px;
  background-color: #071;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 6px #0f2 inset;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  top:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
  animation: eyesTrackBall 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.left {left: calc(50% - 35px);}
.right {left: calc(50% + 6px);}

.eyeWatch{
  width: 7px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left:20px;
  transform:rotate(25deg);
  animation: trackIt 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  overflow:hidden;
}

/* eyes light reflaction */
.glare {
  width:5px;
  height:5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
  top:3px;
  animation: light 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.eyelids {
  width:90px;
  height:1px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top:35px;
  left: calc(50% - 45px);
  background-color: #000;
  animation: blink 6s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.nose{
  width:14px;
  height:5px;
  background-color: pink;
  position:absolute;
  top:70px;
  border-radius:50% 50% 0 0;
  left:calc(50% - 7px);
}

/* cats's claws */
.claws{
  width: 3px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
}

.c1{top: 78px;left: 25px;transform:rotatez(25deg);}
.c2{top: 83px;left: 41px;}
.c3{top: 78px;left: 56px;transform:rotatez(-25deg);}
.c4{top: 78px;right: 25px;transform:rotatez(-25deg);}
.c5{top: 83px;right: 41px;}
.c6{top: 78px;right: 56px;transform:rotatez(25deg);}

/* ball styles */
.ballContainer {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:140px;
}

.ball {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 1px -1px 3px #000 inset;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:absolute;
  animation: ballLight 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.ballShadow{
  width:20px;
  height:15px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: calc(50% + 90px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff inset;
  animation: ballRolling 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

/* animations */
/* eyes traking the ball */
@keyframes trackIt {
  from{
    margin-left:21px;
    transform:rotate(25deg);
  }
  to{
    margin-left:0px;
    transform:rotate(-25deg);
  }
}
/* eye green shadow moving after the balls movement*/
@keyframes eyesTrackBall {
  from{box-shadow: 5px 5px 6px #0f2 inset;}
  to {box-shadow: -5px 5px 6px #0f2 inset;}
}
/* light for the eyes glare */
@keyframes light {
  0%{transform: translateX(-2px);opacity:3;}
  50%{opacity:1;}
  100%{transform: translateX(4px);opacity:3;}
}
/* eyelids animation */
@keyframes blink {
  0%{height: 1px;}
  3%{height: 35px;}
  4%{height: 1px;}
  100%{height: 1px;}
}

/* ball roll animation along with animation for it shadow to reflect the light */
@keyframes ballRolling {
  0%{margin-left: calc(50% + 90px);}
  100%{margin-left: calc(50% - 90px);}
}

@keyframes ballLight {
  0%{
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 3px #000 inset;
    margin: -10px 0 0 -3px;
  }
  100%{
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 3px #000 inset;
    margin: -10px 0 0 3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cat"><img src="https://github.com/Martichka9/stalking-cat-loader/blob/master/imgs/silhouette-snout-logo-wall-mammal.png?raw=true" />
        <div class="eyelids"></div>
        <div class="eye left">
            <div class="eyeWatch">
                <div class="glare"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="eye right">
            <div class="eyeWatch">
                <div class="glare"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nose"></div>
        <div class="claws c1"></div>
        <div class="claws c2"></div>
        <div class="claws c3"></div>
        <div class="claws c4"></div>
        <div class="claws c5"></div>
        <div class="claws c6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ballContainer">
        <div class="ballShadow">
            <div class="ball"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ears">
        <div class="ear eLeft"></div>
        <div class="ear eRight"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: изображение кота надо в svg сделать и менять у него цвет заливки)

Comment: C png изображением можете разве что попробовать [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Используйте filter, [вот пример генератора](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp)

```css
.wrapper {
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
height:95vh;
}
/* cat body */
.cat {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  height: 100px;
/*   margin: 20px auto; */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.cat img {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  top: -46px;
  filter: invert(8%) sepia(100%) saturate(7374%) hue-rotate(247deg) brightness(93%) contrast(145%);
}

/* cat's years styles */
.ears{
  position:absolute
}

.ear {
  width:0;
  border-left:10px solid transparent;
  border-right:10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:20px solid pink;
  position: relative;
}

.eLeft {
  left: -49px;
  top: -16px;
  transform: rotate(-48deg);
}
.eRight {
  left: 49px;
  top: -36px;
  transform: rotate(48deg);
}

/* cat's eyes */
.eye {
  position: absolute;
  width:28px;
  height:28px;
  background-color: #071;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 6px #0f2 inset;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  top:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
  animation: eyesTrackBall 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.left {left: calc(50% - 35px);}
.right {left: calc(50% + 6px);}

.eyeWatch{
  width: 7px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left:20px;
  transform:rotate(25deg);
  animation: trackIt 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  overflow:hidden;
}

/* eyes light reflaction */
.glare {
  width:5px;
  height:5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
  top:3px;
  animation: light 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.eyelids {
  width:90px;
  height:1px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top:35px;
  left: calc(50% - 45px);
  background-color: #000;
  animation: blink 6s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.nose{
  width:14px;
  height:5px;
  background-color: pink;
  position:absolute;
  top:70px;
  border-radius:50% 50% 0 0;
  left:calc(50% - 7px);
}

/* cats's claws */
.claws{
  width: 3px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
}

.c1{top: 78px;left: 25px;transform:rotatez(25deg);}
.c2{top: 83px;left: 41px;}
.c3{top: 78px;left: 56px;transform:rotatez(-25deg);}
.c4{top: 78px;right: 25px;transform:rotatez(-25deg);}
.c5{top: 83px;right: 41px;}
.c6{top: 78px;right: 56px;transform:rotatez(25deg);}

/* ball styles */
.ballContainer {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:140px;
}

.ball {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 1px -1px 3px #000 inset;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:absolute;
  animation: ballLight 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.ballShadow{
  width:20px;
  height:15px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: calc(50% + 90px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff inset;
  animation: ballRolling 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

/* animations */
/* eyes traking the ball */
@keyframes trackIt {
  from{
    margin-left:21px;
    transform:rotate(25deg);
  }
  to{
    margin-left:0px;
    transform:rotate(-25deg);
  }
}
/* eye green shadow moving after the balls movement*/
@keyframes eyesTrackBall {
  from{box-shadow: 5px 5px 6px #0f2 inset;}
  to {box-shadow: -5px 5px 6px #0f2 inset;}
}
/* light for the eyes glare */
@keyframes light {
  0%{transform: translateX(-2px);opacity:3;}
  50%{opacity:1;}
  100%{transform: translateX(4px);opacity:3;}
}
/* eyelids animation */
@keyframes blink {
  0%{height: 1px;}
  3%{height: 35px;}
  4%{height: 1px;}
  100%{height: 1px;}
}

/* ball roll animation along with animation for it shadow to reflect the light */
@keyframes ballRolling {
  0%{margin-left: calc(50% + 90px);}
  100%{margin-left: calc(50% - 90px);}
}

@keyframes ballLight {
  0%{
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 3px #000 inset;
    margin: -10px 0 0 -3px;
  }
  100%{
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 3px #000 inset;
    margin: -10px 0 0 3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cat"><img src="https://github.com/Martichka9/stalking-cat-loader/blob/master/imgs/silhouette-snout-logo-wall-mammal.png?raw=true" />
        <div class="eyelids"></div>
        <div class="eye left">
            <div class="eyeWatch">
                <div class="glare"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="eye right">
            <div class="eyeWatch">
                <div class="glare"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nose"></div>
        <div class="claws c1"></div>
        <div class="claws c2"></div>
        <div class="claws c3"></div>
        <div class="claws c4"></div>
        <div class="claws c5"></div>
        <div class="claws c6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ballContainer">
        <div class="ballShadow">
            <div class="ball"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ears">
        <div class="ear eLeft"></div>
        <div class="ear eRight"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```